# C# Alarm system loop issue

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback, system, alarm

I am about to build a alarm system. The way it works is by pulling date/time information from a gridview column, then I use a async action to check when the time now is equal to one or more of the rows in the gridview date/time column, if it is then show an alarm.

Everything works fine so far, except that when 2 rows contains the same date/time, the alarm will trigger 4 times instead of 2. This is what I got so far:

```
    string firma = "";
    private void radButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < radGridView4.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DateTime executionTime = Convert.ToDateTime(radGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString());
                ScheduleAction(action, executionTime);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    public async void ScheduleAction(Action action, DateTime ExecutionTime)
    {
        try
        {
            if (DateTime.Now < ExecutionTime)//ExecutionTime only create an alarm for rows that are later than now
            {
                await Task.Delay((int)ExecutionTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);

                action();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    public void action()
    {
        RadDesktopAlert Alert;
        for (int i = 0; i < radGridView4.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime executionTime = Convert.ToDateTime(radGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString());

            if (DateTime.Now.Date == executionTime.Date && DateTime.Now.Hour == executionTime.Hour && DateTime.Now.Minute == executionTime.Minute)
            {
                Alert = new RadDesktopAlert();

                firma = radGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

                Alert.CaptionText = "Telefonmøde";
                Alert.ContentText = firma;
                Alert.Show();

            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, and everything works without errors without the try statement aswell.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you're *scheduling* duplicate alarms, and the other part is that your action is going to also *trigger* duplicate alarms, because both of these blocks of code is looping through your grid.

It might help if the `action` method does not depend on data in the grid, but rather gets everything it needs through it's arguments. This means we should capture the `content` the first time we loop through the grid items, and then pass this info to the method.

To do this, we can modify the `action` method to take a string for the content, and we can remove the looping of the grid. Note that if we now call `action`, it will just execute the action right away, so it's up to the caller to schedule it at the correct time:

```
public void action(string content)
{
    var alert = new RadDesktopAlert
    {
        CaptionText = "Telefonmøde",
        ContentText = content
    };

    alert.Show();
}
```

Now that we've modified the `action` method, we also need to modify the `ScheduleAction` method so that it passes the new required parameter. This means that it will also need to take a new parameter:

```
public async void ScheduleAction(Action<string> action, string content, 
    DateTime ExecutionTime)
{
    if (DateTime.Now < ExecutionTime)
    {
        await Task.Delay((int)ExecutionTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
        action(content);
    }
}
```

Next, we could create a separate `List<DataTime>` object to keep track of the times we've already scheduled. Then, as we loop through the grid view, we only schedule a time if it's not in in the list. We also capture the `content` data while we're at it:

```
var scheduledExecutionTimes = new List<DateTime>();

for (int i = 0; i < radGridView4.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DateTime executionTime = Convert.ToDateTime(radGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString());

    if (!scheduledExecutionTimes.Contains(executionTime))
    {            
        string content = radGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        ScheduleAction(action, content, executionTime);

        // Add this time to our list
        scheduledExecutionTimes.Add(executionTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose this block of code is supposed to be inside the button right?

var scheduledExecutionTimes = new List<DateTime>();

for (int i = 0; i < radGridView4.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DateTime executionTime = Convert.ToDateTime(radGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString());

    if (!scheduledExecutionTimes.Contains(executionTime))
    {            
        string content = radGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        ScheduleAction(action, content, executionTime);

        // Add this time to our list
        scheduledExecutionTimes.Add(executionTime);
    }
}

Comment: And the problem is I need it to support same date/time values, but again only make the alarm show once, your code is inspiring, but could we do it in a way so it could support my needs?

Comment: After studying your code abit more, I realized I could just remove the if (!scheduledExecutionTimes.Contains(executionTime)) line in order to archieve what I wanted. Thanks alot man been working on this for days now!

Answer (score 0):

You may put `break` after calling `Alert.Show()`:

```
public void action()
{
    RadDesktopAlert Alert;
    for (int i = 0; i < radGridView4.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DateTime executionTime = Convert.ToDateTime(radGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString());

        if (DateTime.Now.Date == executionTime.Date && DateTime.Now.Hour == executionTime.Hour && DateTime.Now.Minute == executionTime.Minute)
        {
            Alert = new RadDesktopAlert();

            firma = radGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

            Alert.CaptionText = "Telefonmøde";
            Alert.ContentText = firma;
            Alert.Show();
            break; // This will prevent duplicate alarms
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is still showing duplicate but now it only shows 1 of the rows. Note that the action() itself is inside a loop, witch is kind of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found @Rufus L's solution very usefull, the only change I made in the 3 blocks of code was to remove the if (!scheduledExecutionTimes.Contains(executionTime)) in order to archieve my goal. Hope this becomes usefull to somebody else, as it has been a struggle for me.

```
    var scheduledExecutionTimes = new List<DateTime>();

for (int i = 0; i < radGridView4.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DateTime executionTime = Convert.ToDateTime(radGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString());

    if (!scheduledExecutionTimes.Contains(executionTime))
    {            
        string content = radGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        ScheduleAction(action, content, executionTime);

        // Add this time to our list
        scheduledExecutionTimes.Add(executionTime);
    }
}
```

Thanks!